# Rails Render Helper Not Rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering, partial-views

One of my helper functions to render partials is not rendering correctly.

```
    def render_contact_list
      @contact_groups = ContactGroup.find(:all, :conditions => ["user_id = ?", current_user.id])

      @contact_groups.each do |contact_group|
        @contacts = Contact.find(:all, :conditions => ["group_id = ? and Owner_id = ?", contact_group.id, current_user.id])
        render :text => "#{contact_group.name}<br />"
        render(:partial => 'contacts/partials/view_contacts', :collection => @contacts, :as => :contact)
      end
  end
```

All that displays on the page is

```
##
```

When looking at the HTML of the rendered page, it looks like this:

```
#<ContactGroup:0x103090c78>#<ContactGroup:0x103090b60>
```

I commented out the block function completely and it still displayed the above.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**: I just realized that the ## is coming from @contact_groups being the last value assigned on the page. It is returning the value and not rendering any of the code within the block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your helper function is returning the list `@contact_groups`. You need to return the partial instead. You might do it like this (rough example):

```
def render_contact_list
  @contact_groups = ContactGroup.find(:all, :conditions => ["user_id = ?", current_user.id])

  text = ""
  @contact_groups.each do |contact_group|
    @contacts = Contact.find(:all, :conditions => ["group_id = ? and Owner_id = ?", contact_group.id, current_user.id])
      text << render :text => "#{contact_group.name}<br />"
      text << render(:partial => 'contacts/partials/view_contacts', :collection => @contacts, :as => :contact)
    end
    text
  end
```

Here, we build a string with all the partially-rendered pieces, then return that string (by mentioning it last). The fact that it worked with and without the block is a coincidence; both the first line of your function and the block evaluate to the same thing.

Comment: Thanks so much, worked great. But, I would like to point out that in this scope, render_to_string doesn't work -- You still have to use render.